# How can you generate a JFrame in a Random Location?

Tags: java, swing, random, jframe

As in wen you run any output in a frame, every time you run the program it pops on a different position on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.util.Random`'s `nextInt(int)` along with `JFrame.setLocation(int, int)`.

For example,

```
frame.setLocation(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500));
```

Comment: And GraphicsEnvironment/GraphicsDevice to get the screen size.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`setLocation(int, int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) of `JFrame` to locate a `JFrame` in a new location.

So, put this in the frame's constructor and use [`Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to generate a random location, and your frame will pop up in a random location every time.

Another option would be to override the `setVisible(boolean)` method of the JFrame.

```
public void setVisible(boolean visible){
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (visible) {
        Random r = new Random();
        // Find the screen size
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
        // randomize new location taking into account
        // the screen size, and current size of the window
        int x = r.nextInt(d.x - getWidth());
        int y = r.nextInt(d.y - getHeight());
        setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

The code located inside the `if (visible)` block could be moved inside the constructor.  The `getWidth()` and `getHieght()` methods may not return the correct values that you expect though.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an error such as `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nextInt(int) from the type Random`
you can use the alternative code, `frame.setLocation((int)Math.random(), (int)Math.random());`

Hope this helps!